# improper integral of (cosx+coshx)/ex

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

the question is : set F(x) = $\int_1^x \frac{\cos t+ \cosh t}{e^t}dt$ ,
what $\lim_{x\to\infty}{F(x)}$ equal to ?

my thought:

1. first i think this ask about FTC2 , so F'(x) = f(x) but obviously no help about the question,
2. by obsservation, as x tends to infinity, F(x) is just a improper integral ,and calculate the integral as usual by parts integration, so i get a bunch of junk which is not correct answer ,now i don't know how to do

the acutal question as picture follows [image]

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici sorry sir how about this ?

Comment: Hint: for large $t$, what is the integrand's asymptotic behaviour? What does that tell you about the definite integral $F$?

Comment: @J.G. for large t , the integrand definitly tends to zero, ? because e^t tends to large

Comment: @DanielClarke can you write $\cosh x$ in terms of exponentials?

Comment: @Andrei how ? i google it, coshx expressd as exponential terms is ok , but expressing  cosx in terms of exponentials , imaginary numbers will involve into

Comment: You don't need to. $\cos x/e^x\le e^{-x}$. So the integral of the cosine part is going to be finite.

Comment: oh, i even don't need to compute the integeral of ?cosx/e^x, two parts convergent, and one 1/2 part divergent, am i thinking right this way ?

Comment: Yes. If only one term is divergent, the sum is divergent. If more than one term is divergent you need to check if divergences cancel each other. For example $\int_0^1x^{-1}dx$ is divergent, and so is $\int_0^1(x+1)^{-1}dx$, but the difference is convergent.

Comment: @Andrei Yeh, i guess i understand, but one last question if x tends to minus-infinity(t tends to minus-infinity), those three pieces of this improper all divergent i think, how do i deal with it ?

Comment: Then it becomes more complicated :) You might need to explicitly write the solution (maybe complex integrals)

Comment: @Andrei  i see, thank you sir

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As $$\frac{\cosh(t)}{e^t} = \frac{1+e^{-2t}}2,$$ and the integral of $1/2$ is $t/2$, I think the definite integral should be infinite as $\cos(x)/e^x$ and $e^{-2t}/2$ approach $0$.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your equations

Comment: How do you do this?

Comment: See my edits. Or a quick [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know it was possible for you to edit another user's comment!(presumably most users can't)

Comment: When you get enough reputation, you can edit answers, not comments.

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining.

Comment: By the way, congratulations for joining MSE and posting an answer.

Comment: yeh,  i see,  but i have another question : why don't calculate the integral of cost/e^x and e^-2t ? as t tends to infinite these two convergent? and 1/2 divergent?

Comment: Yes, they are but I am not sure to what cos(t)/e^t converges without integrating, which might be more difficult.

Comment: I think the indefinite integral of e^-2t is -e^(-2t)/2 and the indefinite integral of cos(t)/e^t is (sin(t)e^-t -cos(t) e^-t  ) /2  . As you can see both of these will approach 0 as t approaches infinity.